# Checkbox value showing using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show my checkbox value when I check it, but my code show only one value.

For example if I check 1st checkbox it show it's value at that time. If I check 2nd checkbox then it's value will display beside previous value.

What should I do?

```
<script>
function test(item) {
  var result = $('#val').val();
  $('#course').html(result);
} 
</script>

<html>
  <div id="show">
    <span id="course"> </span>
  </div>

  <input type="checkbox" id="val" value="20" onclick="test()" />20
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="val" value="30" onclick="test()" />30
  <br />
  <input type="checkbox" id="val" value="40" onclick="test()" />40
  <br />
</html>
```

Comment: id be unique in html

Comment: change `$('#course').html(result);` to `$('#course').append(result);` also you `this` context and to get current checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note -

1. You should have to use unique id
2. my suggestion is use class instead

Please refer this, i hope will be useful to you

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.chk_val').on('click',function(){
var result = $(this).val();
  $('#course').append(result);
  
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show">
<span id="course"> </span>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" class="chk_val" value="20" />20
<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="chk_val" value="30" />30
<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="chk_val" value="40" />40
<br />
```

Comment: Thanks. when i uncheck it. It will append value . I want to remove that.

Answer (score 1):

```js
  $('input[data-action="data-click"]').on("click", function() {
        if($(this). prop("checked")==true){
            var dataDisplay = "<span id='" + this.value + "'>" + this.value + "</span>";
            $('div#show').append(dataDisplay + " ")
        }
        else {
        $("#" + this.value).remove();
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <div id="show">
 
</div>
<input type="checkbox" value="20" data-action="data-click" />20
<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="30" data-action="data-click" />30
<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="40" data-action="data-click" />40
<br />
```

Comment: Thanks. when i uncheck it. It will append value . I want to remove that.

Answer (score 0):

You have given same id to every checkbox so javascript finds only the first checkbox and shows its value.

You can send the `clicked checkbox` to the function and get its value

```
<div id="show"> 
<span id="course"> </span>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" id="val" value="20" onclick="test(this)" />20
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="val2" value="30" onclick="test(this)" />30
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="val3" value="40" onclick="test(this)" />40



<script>
 function test(item) {
   var result = $(item).val();
   $('#course').html(result);
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function test(element) {
  var result = $(element).val();
  $('#course').append(result);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show">
  <span id="course"> </span>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" id="val" value="20" onclick="test(this)" />20
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="val" value="30" onclick="test(this)" />30
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="val" value="40" onclick="test(this)" />40
<br />
```

1. Change $('#course').html(result); to $('#course').append(result);
2. Use `this` context and to get current checkbox

Comment: Thanks. when i uncheck it. It will append value . I want to remove that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `id` attribute should be unique you need to always use `class` attribute for a group of elements.

For referring the clicked element pass `this` as click handler argument.

```html
<script>
  function test(item) {
    document.getElementById('course').innerHTML = item.value;
  }
</script>

<html>
<div id="show">
  <span id="course"> </span>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" value="20" onclick="test(this)" />20
<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="30" onclick="test(this)" />30
<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="40" onclick="test(this)" />40
<br />

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use class instead of id and bind the click event for class

```js
$('.val').click(function() {
   $("#course").html($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<div id="show">
<span id="course"> </span>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" class="val" value="20" />20
<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="val" value="30" />30
<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="val" value="40"  />40
<br />

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Pass the item to the function and display the value of item. I have attached the sample code snippet.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function test(item) {
        var result = item.value;
        $('#course').html(result);
    }
</script>

<html>
<div id="show">
    <span id="course"> </span>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" id="val" value="20" onclick="test(this)" />20
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="val" value="30" onclick="test(this)" />30
<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="val" value="40" onclick="test(this)" />40
<br />

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first Place you should never use same **ID** "val" to all the Check boxes you have **Classes** for that.
This is just a modification to previously entered code, to let you know that you don't have to pass the whole this Object to your function rather you can directly pass the value like **this.value**

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function test(item) {
        var result = item;
        $('#course').html($('#course').html());
    }
</script>

<html>
<div id="show">
    <span id="course"> </span>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" value="20" onclick="test(this.value)" />20
<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="30" onclick="test(this.value)" />30
<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="40" onclick="test(this.value)" />40
<br />

</html>
```

Hope that this helped you.